# Convert String to epoch

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I have a string - 20180915 in format yyyyMMdd
I need to get epoch milli seconds for this date, answer for 20180915 should be 1537012800000

I was able to do this using following function -

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        String myDate = "2018-09-15 12:00:00";
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") );
        System.out.println(localDateTime);
        long millis = localDateTime
                .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(millis);
    }
```

The problem I am facing is -
I am passing String as "2018-09-15 12:00:00" but my input is "20180915". 
I am unable to find good way to convert "20180915" to "2018-09-15 12:00:00" 
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You need to add two `-` to the String as `yyyy` can mean 4 or more digits. i.e. it doesn't stop at 4.

Comment: Parse it as a LocalDate, using the correct pattern, then change the LocalDate to a LocalDateTime by setting the time to MIDNIGHT.

Comment: I wonder why you post this as a comment and not an answer. I'd've upvoted it, @JBNizet

Comment: @iajrz The optimistic part of me is hoping that the OP will try doing it by himself.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @WhiteShadows no, you've turned half of your question into an answer. If you want to post an answer, do that: post an answer, and leave your question as it was, otherwise nobody can understand the question anymore. I've rollbacked to the question as it was initially.

Comment: got it. Thanks for correcting

Comment: Just to make sure we understand correctly, do you mean that in your code you are *parsing* (not passing) String as "2018-09-15 12:00:00"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer -

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");

public static Long getMillisForDate(String date) {
    return LocalDateTime
            .of(LocalDate.parse(date, formatter), LocalTime.NOON)
            .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

Comment: FYI, the code would be more readable (IMHO) if you parsed first and converted after: LocalDate.parse(date, formatter).atTime(LocalTime.NOON)

Comment: I believe that you don’t need to define your own formatter. The built-in `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` can parse your input string.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `DateTimeFormatter` do all the work, which is especially useful if you need to parse multiple dates, as it reduces the number of intermediate parsing steps (and objects created):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuuMMdd")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

String input = "20180915";
long epochMilli = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, fmt).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(epochMilli); // prints: 1537012800000
```

You can replace `OffsetDateTime` with `ZonedDateTime`. Makes no difference to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date with proper mask "yyyyMMdd"

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = format.parse("20180915");
long epochs = date.getTime();
```

Comment: That gives `1536984000000` for me, not the `1537012800000` value requested in the question.

Comment: You should not suggest nor endorse using obsolete classes. [`Date` is such a case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api); use the Java Time API instead.

Comment: @MCEmperor ... Last time I 
 checked date is NOT depricated: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Unfortunately most of the enterprises are still running on J2EE7 so Date is still fair game.

Comment: @Deian I never said it was deprecated, I said it is obsolete - and it is. Many methods within the Date class are deprecated, and the docs themselves mention some cases where the Date class is insufficient. You should not teach people to use this class.

Comment: Please, while I agree completely with @MCEmperor on the general level, this is especially true when the asker is already using java.time, the modern date and time API. When the question is how to use the good tool, why would you suggest using a bad tool instead?